# prototype function and bind in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning about bind in javascript. I need some help here. Can't connect prototype function with another function using bind. It works if the function is inside the class.

Example:

```
let test = {};

test.gen = function () {
    console.log(this.gender);
}
test.age = function () {
    console.log(this.age);
}

class Human {
constructor(gender, age) {
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
}

printInfo() {
    console.log(this.gender);
}
printGender = test.gen.bind(this);
// printAge = test.age.bind(this); // this works
}

Human.prototype.printAge = test.age.bind(this); // gives me undefined


let human = new Human('male', 30);
human.printInfo();
human.printGender();
human.printAge();
```

Comment: Because the this that you are assigning outside of the Class spec, refers to the window in this case :)
This as a keyword in javascript always refers to the current wrapping function scope. If there is none, then you are in the window scope in the browser. So Human.prototype.printAge = test.age.bind(this); <- this refers to the window object and has no idea about your Human class contents

Comment: @Happy Coconut in this line Human.prototype.printAge = test.age.bind(this);  'this' keyword refers to the window object. To check this what you can do is first create the let human = new Human('male', 30); human object than use the bind with human object Human.prototype.printAge = test.age.bind(human);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@noa-dev is correct in that the `this` in the `bind` call is not referring to what you want.

You can simply give the prototype the function and it works correctly:

```
Human.prototype.printAge = test.age
```

Inside the function definition of `test.age`, it is asking for `this.age`. In that case, `this` is defined by the calling context of the function invocation. By placing `test.age` on the prototype of `Human`, which a `Human` instance invokes `human.printAge()` it has `human` as the calling context, so `this` refers to the correct thing inside the function.

The same behavior can be achieved a little more obviously if you put `test.age` directly on an instance:

```
let human = new Human('male', 30)
human.printAge = test.age
human.printAge() // 30
```

The fact that the function `age` is currently living on `test` can act as a red herring and make you think that the `this` inside of it can only be referring to `test`. That's not the case. This code snippet also works, which reflects the behavior of `this` being looked up based on the context of the call:

```
const printAge = function () {
  console.log(this.age)
}

let human = new Human('male', 30)
human.printAge = printAge
human.printAge() // 30
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thanks for your time and explanation;

Comment: So glad to hear it! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Figured I could write it properly here as well.
The reason why

```
Human.prototype.printAge = test.age.bind(this); // gives me undefined
```

Gives you undefined is, because in javascript the "this" keyword always refers to the next bigger wrapping function scope. In your case it is most likely the window scope and the window has no idea about the class contents.

In order to achieve what you want you can bind the function call to the human instance like in the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/v6ye2b0f/1/

```
class Human {
    constructor(age) {
    this.age = age || 0;
  }
}

const human = new Human(30);

console.log(human.age); // 30;

const ageLogger = function() {
    console.log(this.age);
}


Human.prototype.logAge = ageLogger.bind(human);
ageLogger.call(human); // 30
human.logAge(); // 30
```